# static files inside public folder not working in PHP MVC Archteicture

Tags: javascript, php, css, file, model-view-controller

structure of my project

- core

  Router.php
- http

  - controllers

    index.php
- public

  css

  js

  img

  index.php
- views

routes.php

**index.php code**

```
<?php

use Core\Router;

const BASE_PATH = __DIR__.'/../';

session_start();

require BASE_PATH.'vendor/autoload.php';
require BASE_PATH.'Core/functions.php';
require BASE_PATH.'bootstrap.php';

$router = new Router();

require BASE_PATH.'routes.php';


$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'];
$method = $_POST['_method'] ?? $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

try {
    $router->route($uri, $method);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Router.php code**

```
<?php

namespace Core;

use Core\Middleware\Middleware;
use Exception;
use JetBrains\PhpStorm\NoReturn;

class Router
{
    protected array $routes = [];

    public function get($uri, $controller): void
    {
        $this->add('GET', $uri, $controller);
    }

    public function add($method, $uri, $controller): static
    {
        $this->routes[] = [
            'uri' => $uri,
            'controller' => $controller,
            'method' => $method,
            'middleware' => null
        ];

        return $this;
    }

    public function post($uri, $controller): void
    {
        $this->add('POST', $uri, $controller);
    }

    public function delete($uri, $controller): static
    {
        return $this->add('DELETE', $uri, $controller);
    }

    public function patch($uri, $controller): static
    {
        return $this->add('PATCH', $uri, $controller);
    }

    public function put($uri, $controller): static
    {
        return $this->add('PUT', $uri, $controller);
    }

    public function only($key): static
    {
        $this->routes[array_key_last($this->routes)]['middleware'] = $key;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function route($uri, $method)
    {
        foreach ($this->routes as $route) {
            if ($route['uri'] === $uri && $route['method'] === strtoupper($method)) {
                Middleware::resolve($route['middleware']);

                return require base_path('Http/controllers/'.$route['controller']);
            }
        }

        $this->abort();
    }

    #[NoReturn] protected function abort($code = 404): void
    {
        http_response_code($code);

        require base_path("views/{$code}.php");

        die();
    }

    public function previousUrl()
    {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }


}
```

**routes.php code**

```
<?php
/** @var Router $router */

use Core\Router;

$router->get('/', 'index.php');
$router->get('/contact', 'contact.php');
$router->get('/about', 'about.php');
$router->get('/service', 'service.php');
$router->get('/menu', 'menu.php');
$router->get('/team', 'team.php');
$router->get('/testimonial', 'testimonial.php');
$router->get('/booking', 'booking/booking.php');

$router->get('/register', 'register/create.php');
$router->get('/login', 'session/create.php');

$router->get('/cart', 'cart/index.php');
```

all static files and libraries that exist in public folder not work in other pages in the project when i call them.

I run the project in the public folder using php -S lcoalhost:8080

i try to change the path of the static files but it doesn't work, also i tried adding .htaccess to the project but also doesn't work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: i mean the static files js css lib images that presented in public folder not working in other pages when i call them

Answer (score 0):

That's because you php's built in "server" is not, well, real server (for lack of better description). You should learn how to set up an nginx/fpm server using docker.

Buuut, in short runt, you can create a separate file, which attempts to load the existing files, before running it against `index.php`.

You change the server initialization command to something like:
`php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 ./public/built-in.php`

Kinda like in [this exercise](https://github.com/teresko/orange-exercise/blob/master/public/built-in.php) (it's a bit out of date, but should explain the idea).